# Como executar duas funções javascript no carregamento da página PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho duas funções javascript que devem ser executadas no carregamento da página em PHP. As duas são parecidas. Eis uma delas:

```
<?php
if ($idAluno == $idRespA) {

    echo '<script> window.onload = function(){ funcaoA() }; </script>';

} else {

    $respA = $db->select('tbl_pessoas',['*'],['id'=>$idRespA]);

}
?>
```

A segunda parte é a mesma coisa. Só muda o IF, que compara com outra variável e se for vedadeiro executa a funcaoB(). Mas é praticamente a mesma coisa. Ambas são executadas na inicialização da página, uma seguida da outra.

O problema é que ao executá-la só funciona o 'window.onload' de uma delas. Então imagino que essa não deva ser a melhor forma de executar um JS na inicialização.

Como seria uma forma de executar JS dentro de IFs no PHP na inicialização da página?

Também me falaram que não é bom executar funções JS direto no PHP. Por que?

Comment: Tb não entendi o porquê de não executar uma função JS no PHP, já que uma coisa nada tem a ver com outra. O `echo` nada mais é do que retornar um HTML.

Comment: O `onload` só será carregado uma única vez. Você pode criar uma variável, por exemplo: `$script[] = " funcaoA(); "` e `$script[] = "funcaoB();"` e depois basta utilizar `echo "<script>window.onload =
 function() { ".implode("", $script)." }</script>"`. Mas evite fazer isso. Isso é gambiarra e pode lhe causar problemas futuramente.

Comment: coloque `window.onload = function(){ funcaoA(), funcaoB() }`

Answer (score 0):

Pode user `window.addEventListener("load",...` mais de uma vez:

```
<?php
if ($x == $y) {
    echo '<script>
    window.addEventListener("load",function(){
       funcaoA();
    });
    </script>';
}

if ($a == $b) {
    echo '<script>
    window.addEventListener("load",function(){
       funcaoB();
    });
    </script>';
}
?>
```

Quanto a *chamar* funções JS via PHP não vejo problema algum. O PHP apenas retorna código HTML para o navegador. O que você precisa ter cautela é como validar as variáveis que irão permitir que o script seja *escrito* e executado no navegador. Mas isso já é outro departamento.

Comment: Assim não funciona. Pois como eu havia dito, são dois IF. Um para a "funcaoA" e outro para a "funcaoB" (um if após o outro). Ao passar pelo primeiro IF, a "funcaoB" também é executada. E esta só poderá ser executada se passar no segundo IF.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. Abs!

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido com jQuery. Assim:

```
<?php
if ($idAluno == $idRespA) {

    echo '
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            funcaoA();
    });

    </script>
    ';

} else {

    $respA = $db->select('tbl_pessoas',['*'],['id'=>$idRespA]);

}
?>
```

Como falado, logo abaixo tem um outro "if" muito parecido com o de cima. Assim como o primeiro, executa ou não a função correspondente a ele (a "funcaoA" para o primeiro "if" e a "funcaoB" para o segundo "if"). Agora ambos tem o funcionamento esperado.

Obrigado a todos!